# Group items by total amount

Tags: c#, .net, linq, group-by

Suppose I have this number list:

```
List<int> nu = new List<int>();
nu.Add(2);
nu.Add(1);
nu.Add(3);
nu.Add(5);
nu.Add(2);
nu.Add(1);
nu.Add(1);
nu.Add(3);
```

Keeping the list items in the same order, is it possible to group the items in linq that are sum of 6 so results would be something like this:

```
2,1,3 - 5 - 2,1,1 - 3
```

Comment: Your result is not grouping by `less than 7`. All numbers are less than 7.

Comment: The sum of every group is less than 7

Comment: Why would (2,1,3) be in a spearate group to (5)? They're both less than 7

Comment: Do you mean the Sum must be less than 7 ?

Comment: What if a single term is over your maximum?

Comment: single term will only be 1 to 6

Comment: The moral of the story is: it's easy to write your own extensions to IEnumerable. See sixlettervariables' answer for the exension method in your case. Then you can write your query in method notation: `var clusters = nu.[other terms if desired...].GroupBySum(7);`

Comment: @jmh_gr - I think the moral of the story is no one (not even skeet) knows how to use Aggregate

Comment: Thanks you to everyone's reply, just don't no which solution to use lol

Comment: @Chris - as Jon says, use the one you think is clearer. :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could do it with Aggregate.

(Side note:  Use LinqPad to test/write these types of queries, makes it easy)

Gives these results:

[image: results]

Like this:

```
class Less7Holder
{
   public List<int> g = new List<int>();
   public int mySum = 0;
}

void Main()
{
    List<int> nu = new List<int>();
    nu.Add(2);
    nu.Add(1);
    nu.Add(3);
    nu.Add(5);
    nu.Add(2);
    nu.Add(1);
    nu.Add(1);
    nu.Add(3);

    var result  = nu .Aggregate(
       new LinkedList<Less7Holder>(),
       (holder,inItem) => 
       {
          if ((holder.Last == null) || (holder.Last.Value.mySum + inItem >= 7))
          {
            Less7Holder t = new Less7Holder();
            t.g.Add(inItem);
            t.mySum = inItem;
            holder.AddLast(t);
          }
          else
          {
            holder.Last.Value.g.Add(inItem);
            holder.Last.Value.mySum += inItem;
          }
          return holder;
       },
       (holder) => { return holder.Select((h) => h.g );} );

   result.Dump();

}
```

Answer (score 6):

Solving this with LINQ directly would be bothersome, instead you could make an extension method:

```
// Assumptions:
//  (1) All non-negative, or at least you don't mind them in your sum
//  (2) Items greater than the sum are returned by their lonesome
static IEnumerable<IEnumerable<int>> GroupBySum(this IEnumerable<int> source,
    int sum)
{
    var running = 0;
    var items = new List<int>();
    foreach (var x in source)
    {
        if (running + x > sum && items.Any())
        {
            yield return items;
            items = new List<int>();
            running = 0;
        }

        running += x;
        items.Add(x);
    }

    if (items.Any()) yield return items;
}
```

Comment: I was writing similar code myself - but why call `ToArray` each time and clear the existing list? Why not just return the list and create a new one each time?

Comment: Good 'ol SE quick draw contest. I was 73% finished with the same extension method when this posted.

Comment: @sixlettervariables - Is my solution really "bothersome"?  It seems exactly linqy to me.

Comment: @Hogan: I think it's a bit impractical when compared to a simple extension method, but certainly possible as you've shown.

Comment: @sixlettervariables -- I don't get it, it is the same number of lines of code.  The whole point of Linq is to solve problems with quick inline functions, not write helper functions.  This isn't Java.

Comment: @JonSkeet - What do you think as someone who has written a Linq, is six's more Linqy or mine?

Comment: @Hogan: Your approach is more "Linqy" in terms of *using* LINQ - but this one is clearer IMO.